# How to call method from a java class (not an activity, no layout) to an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, listactivity

I cannot use intents, reason is stated below. Also, I tried calling the method, but it is throwing `NullPointerException`.

What I'm trying to do is to send String `songName` from a `ListActivity` to a class which has a method `getSongIndex()`, which compares the incoming String (`songName`) to songs in the `ArrayList` and then returns the index (integer) to the calling activity.

**Reason why I can't use intents:** 
If I send an intent from `ListActivity's` `onClickListener` to the java class, the `getIntent.getExtras()` on the receiving side would cause errors. Also, I'd need another intent in java class to send the `songIndex` back to `ListActivity`.

Here is the required code:

> This is the function in java class: **SongsManager.java**  This is
>   how I get songName in the method and compare it to songtitles in the
>   phone:

```
  public int songIndex;
ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
public int getSongIndex(String s, Context c) {
    String songName = s;
    String songTitle;
    String song;
    final Cursor mCursor = c.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE}, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");
    /* run through all the columns we got back and save the data we need into the arraylist for our listview*/
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            song = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;//mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            songs.add(song);

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

    }
    String tempSong;
    for(int i=0; i <songs.size();i++) {
        tempSong = songs.get(i);
        if(songName.equalsIgnoreCase(tempSong))
        {
            songIndex = i;
        }

    }

    mCursor.close(); //cursor has been consumed so close it
    return songIndex;
}
```

This is how I instantiated the SongsManager object in ListActivity: 
`public SongsManager manager = new SongsManager();`

This is the code in ListActivity's onClickListener that calls the function getSongIndex.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                String songName = textView.getText().toString();
                songIndex = manager.getSongIndex(songName);
                // Starting new intent
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                Log.d("TAG", "onItemClick");
                //// Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                i.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

I am looking for a way to solve or hack this problem. Is there a way to solve this using intents (note that, my ListActivity already recieves an intent from another activity in it's onCreate()). I read about BroadcastReciever but it looks really troublesome. Any other easy way would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: "Reason why I can't use intents: ... the getIntent.getExtras() on the receiving side would cause errors." - so will fixing those errors enable you to use Intents? The way you describe your use case, I think Intents are the right way to go.

Comment: new JavaClassName().methodName(); works fine to call a method.

Comment: It is returning `NullPointerExceptions`. two of them. read my comment on the answer by @ρяσѕρєя K below and the code above to get details.

Comment: @Egor you were saying about intents. Is there a way out with them? Coz I'm back to square one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is :

```
final Cursor mCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(...
```

line.

Because  `SongsManager` is normal java  class then how `getApplicationContext()` method accessible in it?

Means Activity or any other component is extended in `SongsManager` class but not registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`

So, to fix this issue remove class which u have extended in `SongsManager` and pass Context in `getSongIndex` method to access `getContentResolver()`.like:

```
public int getSongIndex(String s,Context mContext) {
     String songName = s;
     String songTitle;
     final Cursor mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(...);
     ...
  return songIndex;
}
```

and call `getSongIndex` method as:

```
songIndex = manager.getSongIndex(songName,getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: You mean I pass `Context()` as an additional parameter to `songName`?

Comment: IDE was showing that red zig-zag underline for `Context()` but it was not showing any error for `getApplicationContext()`, so I passed it. But during run of app, I get two `NullPointerExceptions` now. one at `songs.add(song);` of `getSongIndex(String s, Context c)` and another at `songIndex = manager.getSongIndex(songName, getApplicationContext());` of the `ListActivity`

Comment: @Amenhotep: Still getting error? please show ur updated code

Comment: hey! suddenly the error stopped. IDK why, but now the problem changed: The `ListActivity` is getting songIndex = 0 no matter what. I literally hardcoded songIndex = 7 in SongsManager, just before the return statement of method. But it still player the first song (song at songIndex = 0)

Comment: @Amenhotep: Show how u are getting it in next Activity

Comment: I edited the code for you to see how I get the songName and compare it to songs in the device. I think the mistake is there.

Comment: Hey! It worked! I used `song = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;` instead of `song = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));` and this was causing the songIndex = 0 to get played! After hours, finally! Im new to this, and this feeling after accidentally solving this, still without even completely understanding of this...this is thrilling man! How many years, till I get to your level of expertise?